# ¿Existe una función wordpress para asignar imagen destacada?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Estoy desarrollando un plugin en el que tengo que poner una imagen por defecto para todas las entradas. Las entradas que no tengan imagen destacada asignada, se les debe asignar la que suba al servidor desde el panel del plugin que desarrollo. Sé que wordpress tiene funciones para obtener y cambiar el tamaño de una imagen, el titulo, etc. Pero no he sido capaz de encontrar una función para asignar una imagen destacada a una entrada.

Comment: No entiendo lo que preguntas. ¿Puedes desarrollar más tu pregunta?

Comment: Estoy desarrollando un plugin en el que tengo que poner una imagen por defecto para todas las entradas. Las entradas que no tengan imagen destacada asignada, se les debe asignar la que suba al servidor desde el panel del plugin que desarrollo. Sé que wordpress tiene funciones para obtener y cambiar el tamaño de una imagen, el titulo, etc. Pero no he sido capaz de encontrar una función para asignar una imagen destacada a una entrada.

Comment: Edita la pregunta no lo pongas como comentario, que los demás te puedan leer la pregunta sin tener que leer todos los comentarios.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails es tu opción. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar **set_post_thumbnail()**.

te falta desarrollar un poco tu pregunta ya que no queda del todo claro lo que buscas, esto podrías solucionarlo añadiendo algo de código con lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora.

Suponiendo que conoces el objeto `$post` sobre el que quieres añadir la imagen destacada y también conoces el id de dicha imagen  podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id );
```

Comment: Gracias. Solucionado